# Oracle Apex - ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hello I'm trying to insert a new employee for my database here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, job_id, salary, department_id)
VALUES (500, 'Alicia', 'Santos', 650.124.0000, 'MK_ASST', 10000, 20)
```

but oracle apex keeps shows this error

```
ORA-00917: missing comma
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 670
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200200", line 656
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1768
```

I dont know where is the missing comma is

Answer (score 1):

Phone number can't be as you put it; enclose it into single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, job_id, salary, department_id)
VALUES (500, 'Alicia', 'Santos', '650.124.0000', 'MK_ASST', 10000, 20)
                                 --------------
```